# error moving file with shutil

Tags: python, file, dir, shutil

I am trying to create a simple function that finds files that begin with a certain string and then move them to a new directory but I keep getting the following kinds of  errors from shutil "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '18-1.pdf'", even though the file exists.

```
import os
import shutil
def mv_files(current_dir,start):
    # start of file name
    start = str(start)
    # new directory ro move files in to
    new_dir = current_dir + "/chap_"+ start
    for _file in os.listdir(current_dir):
        # if directory does not exist, create it
        if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
                os.mkdir(new_dir)
        # find files beginning with start and move them to new dir
        if _file.startswith(start):
            shutil.move(_file, new_dir)
```

Am I using shutil incorrectly?

correct code:

```
import os
import shutil
def mv_files(current_dir,start):
    # start of file name
    start = str(start)
    # new directory ro move files in to
    new_dir = current_dir + "/chap_" + start
    for _file in os.listdir(current_dir):
        # if directory does not exist, create it
        if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
            os.mkdir(new_dir)
       # find files beginning with start and move them to new dir
        if _file.startswith(start):
            shutil.move(current_dir+"/"+_file, new_dir)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you aren't giving the full path to `shutil.move`. Try:

```
if _file.startswith(start):
    shutil.move(os.path.abspath(_file), new_dir)
```

If that fails, try printing `_file`, and `new_dir` along with the result of `os.getcwd()` and adding them to your answer.

Comment: thanks, totally overlooked the fact I was only giving file name and not full path.